# Random walk evaluated by a Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

I found the following proposition and I want to prove it.

> Let $S_n$ be a discrete-time random walk with increment distribution p and $N_t$ be a Poisson process with parameter $1$.Then the process $T_t:=S_{N_t}$ has the distribution of a continuous-time random walk with increment distribution p.

The same literature gives the following definition of a continuous-time random walk:

> A **continuous**-time random walk with increment distribution $p$ is the continuous-time Markov chain $T_t$ with rates $p$, i.e.:

- $\mathbb{P}[T_{t+\Delta t}=y\mid T_t=x]=p(y-x)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$ if $x\neq y$
- $\mathbb{P}[T_{t+\Delta t}=x\mid T_t=x]=1-[\sum_{y\neq x}p(y-x)]\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$ if $x=y$.

> A **discrete**-time random walk with increment distribution $p$ can be seen as a time-homogeneous Markov chain $S_n$ with transition probabilities:

- $p(y,z)=\mathbb{P}[S_{n+1}=z\mid S_n=y]=p(z-y)$

and n-th step distribution

- $p_n(x,y)=\mathbb{P}[S_{n}=y\mid S_0=x]$

So I want now to use the discrete definition to prove the continuous case. Note that $\mathbb{P}[N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]=\frac{e^{-\Delta t}(\Delta t)^k}{k!}$. I want to use this condition so I thought the following:

$\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t+\Delta t}}=y\mid S_{N_t}=x]=\frac{\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t+\Delta t}}=y,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\frac{\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t}+k}=y,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t}+k}=y,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k\mid S_{N_t}=x]}$.

But now I don't see how to go on from there and honestly it does not looks that good..

---

UPDATE

So I tried the following. But I think I still need some help to conclude the proof.

> Want to show: $T_t:=S_{N_t}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with transition probability $p$.
>
> To check: $\mathbb{P}[T_{t+\Delta t}=y\mid T_t=x]=p(y-x)\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$

Using that the discrete-time random walk is a Markov chain with transition probability $p$ we have: $\mathbb{P}[S_{n+1}=z\mid S_n=y]=p(z-y)$

Now from the cmputation we have:
$\mathbb{P}[T_{t+\Delta t}=y\mid T_t=x]=\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t+\Delta t}}=y\mid S_{N_t}=x]=\frac{\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t+\Delta t}}=y,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\frac{\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t}+k}=y,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\frac{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}=y-x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k,S_{N_t}=x]}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}}$

> Now since $S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}\overset{L}{=}S_k$ and $S_k$ is independent of $N_{\Delta t}\overset{L}{=}N_{t+\Delta t}-N_{t}$, we have $S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}$ is independent of $N_{t+\Delta t}-N_{t}$ and also independent of $S_{N_t}$. And finally since the Poisson process has independent increments we also have that $N_{t+\Delta t}-N_{t}$ is independent of $N_{\Delta t}$ and so (since by assumption $N_t$ is independent of $S_n$) is also independent of $S_{N_t}$. So we get:

$=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\frac{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}=y-x]\mathbb{P}[N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{k}=y-x]\mathbb{P}[N_{\Delta t}=k]}=\sum_{k\geq 0}{\mathbb{P}[S_{k}=y-x]\frac{e^{-\Delta t}(\Delta t)^{k}}{k!}}$

So now I think I should use that $S_n$ is a Markov chain to rewrite the term $\mathbb{P}[S_{k}=y-x]$. I was thinking to rewrit it as $\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{P}[S_{k}=y-x\mid S_{k-1}=z]}=\sum_{z\in \mathbb{Z}}{p(y-x-z)}$, but again this does not looks very helpful...

Comment: Would be nice if you could post where you found it as well.

Comment: Actually "it" does look very "good" since $S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}$, $N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t$ and $N_t$ are jointly independent, $S_{N_{t}+k}-S_{N_t}$ is distributed like $S_k$ and $N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t$ is distributed like  $N_{\Delta t}$ hence the very last sum in your post is actually $$\sum_{k\geqslant 0}P(S_k=y-x)P(N_{\Delta t}=k).$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: @Did Thanks for your advice. Actually I still have some problem to get your term. I can rewrite it as follows $\frac{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t+k}=y,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\frac{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t+k}-S_{N_t}=y-x,S_{N_t}=x,N_{t+\Delta t}-N_t=k]}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}=\frac{\mathbb{P}[S_k=y-x]\mathbb{P}[ N_{\Delta t}=k]}{\mathbb{P}[S_{N_t}=x]}$. Could you say me what am I making wrong?

Comment: You forgot $S_{N_t}=x$ in the event on top.

Comment: @Did okay I see. But then keeping this event why are $S_k,\ S_{N_t}, N_{\Delta t}$ independent?

Comment: Hmmm... regarding independence, did you read my *first* comment by any chance?

Comment: @Did yes I did. regarding the independence of $S_k$ and $N_{\Delta t}$ I'm fine. but between $S_{N_{\Delta t}}$ and the others not much.. sorry I do not see it.

Comment: Better to stick to the independence properties actually claimed in my comment, they have the two desirable properties of being true and being sufficient to solve the exercise.

Comment: @Did I tried to work out the part above, but I still have problems to conclude. Could you give me some more advice? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @sky90 did you end-up finishing the proof? I was just thinking about this now.