# Continuation of random walks

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk, poisson-distribution

I have trouble understanding the following identity:
$\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta\cdot T_t}]=\sum_{j\geq 0}{e^{-t}\frac{t^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta\cdot S_j}]}$. I see that somehow it uses the following lemma, which I tried to prove [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492090/random-walk-evaluated-by-a-poisson-process).

> Let $S_n$ be a discrete-time random walk with increment distribution p
>   and $N_t$ be a Poisson process with parameter $1$.Then the process
>   $T_t:=S_{N_t}$ has the distribution of a continuous-time random walk
>   with increment distribution p.

Can someone give me more details between this step? I see it as a strange composition of random variables but I can't clarify this. Thanks

Comment: Hint: At time $t$, the continuous time random walk made a random number of jumps of the discrete random walk, and this number of jumps has Poisson distribution with parameter $t$.

Comment: Two things that may help: 1. the waiting time between jumps in a Poisson process is exponentially distributed. 2. a continuous time Markov chain can be decomposed into a discrete time Markov chain, called the "jump chain", and a family of exponentially distributed "holding time variables" which describe how long the process spends in a given state. You are basically running this decomposition in reverse: starting with $p$, which tells you the jump chain, and then using your Poisson process to assign a continuous distribution to the holding times.

Comment: This is mostly just restating the problem of course, but it gives you some terminology that should be fairly easy to look up.

Comment: May be then as follows? $\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta T_t}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta S(\omega_1)_{N_t(\omega_2)}}]=\int_{\Omega^2}{e^{i\theta f(\omega_1,\omega_2)}dP_{S_n,N_t}(\omega_1,\omega_2)}=\int_\Omega\int_{\Omega}{e^{i\theta f(\omega_1,\omega_2)}dP_{S_n}(\omega_1)}dP_{N_t}(\omega_2)=\sum_{k\geq0}\int_{\Omega}{e^{i\theta f(\omega_1,\omega_2)}dP_{S_n}(\omega_1)}\mathbb{P}[N_t(\omega_2)=k]=$

Comment: $=\sum_{k\geq0}\int_{\Omega}{e^{i\theta S_{N_t(\omega_2)}(\omega_1)}dP_{S_n}(\omega_1)}\mathbb{P}[N_t(\omega_2)=k]=\sum_{k\geq0}\int_{\Omega}{e^{i\theta S_{k}(\omega_1)}dP_{S_n}(\omega_1)}\mathbb{P}[N_t(\omega_2)=k]=\sum_{k\geq0}\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta S_{k}}]\mathbb{P}[N_t(\omega_2)=k]$